# Cannot link bot to bot framework emulator

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot

This is my current screen when I have tried to load my bot into the bot Framework Emulator:[image]

And this is what I have entered within the setting for my bot:[image]

But for some reason my bot framework emulator remains empty.
I have also tried setting the Endpoint URL to http://localhost:3979/api/messages but no luck. I am trying to run this locally off of visual studio.

Any help with this is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you started the bot in VS before connecting? VS should launch a web browser which will confirm the port and listening address

Comment: @JamesDonovan Yes and this is the local host it produces http://localhost:3984

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Comment: this also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0  let me know if its work for you or not @L.Full

Comment: @D-johnAnshani, your link only comments are not really helping here

Comment: Are you using one of the samples or have you written your own code?

Comment: @D-johnAnshani I have looked at both of those documents and they have not solved my issue :(

Comment: @JasonSowers I began with the QnA template and then modified it slightly to greet the user as soon as the conversation is initiated

Comment: i have whole sample and with the help of thinks i have done all these setup

Comment: Can you add a link to the sample (and walkthrough if you are using one) you are using in your question?  We will test the sample and see if we can help you with a workaround.

Comment: @JasonSowers What do you mean by a sample?

Comment: Where did you get the code you are using from?

Comment: @JasonSowers Azure, its from a QnA bot with a slight modification so that the bot initiates a conversation. It runs when I test it in azure and when embedded into sharepoint.

Comment: @JasonSowers The code that allows the bot to greet the user is from a collection of web pages including Microsoft's proactive messaging page.

Comment: Ok, I have a colleague that has a solution for this, she will be posting an answer shortly.

Comment: Hi @L.Full, according to the screenshot that you provided, message is not sent but there are not any error messages appear in LOG window, which is strange. You can try to uninstall and reinstall the Bot Emulator, and then check if you can connect to your bot via Bot Emulator. Besides, you can set breakpoint in MessagesController and check if it can hit the breakpoint when you send message.

Comment: @FeiHan I have reinstalled the emulator, and put a breakpoint at the point where the chat bot greets the user but still no joy. The program does not even reach the breakpoint.

Comment: I have tried the older emulator (v3.5.36) and get these logs which I do not get with the newest version of the emulator. 
`Log
[17:23:40] Emulator listening on http://[::]:64774 
[17:23:40] ngrok not configured (only needed when connecting to remotely hosted bots) 
[17:23:40] Connecting to bots hosted remotely 
[17:23:40] Edit ngrok settings 
[17:23:40] Checking for new version... 
[17:23:42] Application is up to date.`

Answer (score 3):

L. Full, if you followed the [instructions from the Azure portal to create a QnA bot from a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/create-qna-bot#chat-with-the-bot), you will need to tweak the code a bit to have it work locally, and in turn work in the emulator.

After you have created your bot using the template (which it sounds like you have done),  in [ABS](https://ms.portal.azure.com), going to **Build** (under Bot Management)> **"Download zip file"**, you get a copy of your project locally.

If you look at the template Bot code, it works in Azure, because in summary, it is accessing your QnA credentials from within your Application Settings inside the Azure portal, but locally you will need to put the credentials somewhere like your .config file.

Ultimately what we'll have to do now is plug in your QnA credentials into your .config file of your project, as this is not automatically downloaded into the code when you download the zip.

Below I'm just using the QnA Template bot that you can find in the Azure portal (Create Resource > AI + Machine Learning > Web App Bot with Bot template of "Question and Answer")

1. **In *Web.config* add key-value pairs for AzureWebJobsStorage (if using), QnAAuthKey, QnAKnowledgebaseId, and QnAEndpointHostName**
   Your own credential values can be found under *Application Settings* of the Azure portal

   ```
   <appSettings>

   <!-- update these with your Microsoft App Id and your Microsoft App Password-->
   <add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="" />
   <add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="" />

   <add key="AzureWebJobsStorage" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https...."/>
   <add key="QnAAuthKey" value="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
   <add key="QnAKnowledgebaseId" value="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
   <add key="QnAEndpointHostName" value="https://YOURQNA.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker" />
   <add key="QnASubscriptionKey" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
   </appSettings>
   ```
2. **In your Dialog** (QnA template as of 7/5/18 has default dialog file named BasicQnAMakerDialog.cs), **instead of *Utils* (default in template), we'll use *ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"]* to access the values you just placed in your Web.config**:
   Below you can see I've changed the variables (commented out) in QnA template to retrieve values using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings. You may also have to edit the variables in your if-statement as well, depending on the logic your own app needs.

In Root Dialog

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{

                var message = await result as Activity;

                // OLD 
                //var qnaAuthKey = GetSetting("QnAAuthKey"); 
                //var qnaKBId = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAKnowledgebaseId");
                //var endpointHostName = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAEndpointHostName"); 

                // NEW
                var qnaAuthKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAAuthKey"];
                var qnaKBId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"];
                var endpointHostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAEndpointHostName"]; 

                // QnA Subscription Key and KnowledgeBase Id null verification
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qnaAuthKey) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(qnaKBId))
                {
                    // Forward to the appropriate Dialog based on whether the endpoint hostname is present
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endpointHostName))
                        await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerPreviewDialog(), AfterAnswerAsync, message, CancellationToken.None);
                    else
                        await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerDialog(), AfterAnswerAsync, message, CancellationToken.None);

                }
                else
                {
                    await context.PostAsync("Please set QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAAuthKey and QnAEndpointHostName (if applicable) in App Settings. Learn how to get them at https://aka.ms/qnaabssetup.");
                }

            }
```

3. **In the children Dialogs that get called by your root (BasicQnAMakerDialog for example), be sure to also replace anything that calls for a QnA key with ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"]**.

For example in BasicQnAMakerDialog:

```
[Serializable]
public class BasicQnAMakerDialog : QnAMakerDialog
{
        static readonly string qnaAuthKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAAuthKey"]; 
        static readonly string qnaKBId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"];
        static readonly string endpointHostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAEndpointHostName"]; 

        public BasicQnAMakerDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(
            new QnAMakerAttribute
            (
                qnaAuthKey, 
                qnaKBId,
                "No good match in FAQ.", 
                0.5, 
                1, 
                endpointHostName
            )))
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have implemented those steps just now, still no luck. It produces the same output as before (Nothing).

Comment: L. Full I just realized the Web.config code snippet didn't copy the entire code that I had. Did you put the code inside appSettings inside the .config file?

Comment: <appSettings>
    <!-- update these with your Microsoft App Id and your Microsoft App Password-->
    <add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="" />
    <add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="" />

    <add key="AzureWebJobsStorage" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https...."/>
    <add key="QnAAuthKey" value="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="QnAKnowledgebaseId" value="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="QnAEndpointHostName" value="https://YOURQNA.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker" />

  </appSettings>

Comment: I just edited the above answer. Apparently StackOverflow wants specific indentation for code to appear...anyways, the keys you add into your .config file should be inside the <appSettings> tag

Comment: My current code was inside the appSettings and included the keys you mentioned but still does not work.

Comment: Hey @L.Full, when you used the latest version of the emulator (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases) (v4), could you only enter Bot Name (Turvey) and Endpoint URL (http://localhost:XXXX/api/messages), WITHOUT including the app Id and app password--be sure to replace XXXX with your appropriate numbers, ofc, found in the browser window that pops up when you run the project. See if that changes anything?

Comment: Hi @Zeryth thanks for your reply. Tried the Endpoint URL and bot name without app ID or app password, no luck unfortunately

Comment: Hmm...ok. Let's try this. Post the code on GitHub, and we'll go ahead and dive in directly to your code. (Corina let me know what you had asked the question again on GitHub as well) ...and we'll go from there!

Comment: what is your user name so I can grant access? @Zeryth

Comment: it's Zerryth on github (two r's) @L. Full

Comment: I've sent the invite, @Zerryth

Comment: Alright, I tweaked your code a bit. 
In Web.config also added <add key="QnASubscriptionKey" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" /> right below QnAEndpointHostName key
Also it appears in your BasicQnAMakerDialog.cs you still have uses of Utils instead of ConfigurationManager (example line 64 should be var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAAuthKey"]; if you are trying to access the auth key from Web.config) Same with your BasicQnAMakerDialog class, your constructor still makes use of Utils instead of ConfigurationManager.AppSettings (line 111)

Comment: This problem still persists @Zeryth

Comment: Is the 4.0.15-alpha version of the bot framework the correct one to be using? @Zeryth

Comment: If you made the bot from the template in the Azure portal as described in the documentation linked earlier, you would be using SDK v3, the emulator I'm using is v4. And in both the Web.config and emulator I do NOT include the AppId/Password, only the QnA keys (AzureWebJobsStorage, QnAAuthKey, QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAEndpointHostName, and QnASubscriptionKey) are in the Web.Config. So ensure that you have the above and pulled the changes in the code I made. Also, to clarify, you're saying you're not getting any errors at all that we can work with?

Comment: And when you tested the bot in web chat, the bot responded fine to the QnA, correct? It's just locally via emulator where it's not working?

Comment: Yes I have done the above and yes the bot works fine with the QnA in the web chat, its just locally in the emulator it does not work

Comment: This is my process of loading my bot into the bor framework emulator:
1) Download ZIP
2) Enter QnASubscriptionKey, QnAEndpointHostName, QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAAuthKey, and AzureWebJobsStorage information leaving the AppID and AppPassword blank in Visual studio.
3) Run the application on Visual Studio
4) Copy the address in the search bar
5) Enter that address into the Endpoint URL enter the name (Does this have to be specific?)
6) Click submit

Comment: This just results no information being displayed and a completely blank Log

Comment: Also would you like to move this discussion to a chat until we have a solution?

Comment: @ L. Full what operating system are you using? 

This is most likely not a QnAMaker issue, but specifically an emulator issue, given what you've told me so far

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: The version is 1709

Comment: The URL when the code is run in Visual studio is still http://localhost:3984/ would this suggest that the code is still not 100%? @Zeryth

Comment: @L. Full started a chat

Comment: How do I access the chat? @Zeryth

Comment: Apparently it "timed out" after no activity after my initial messages into the room. Try here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177664/lfull-zeryth

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution you can do is:

1. Right click your project in **Solution Explorer** in Visual Studio.
2. Click Properties.
3. Go to **Debug** Tab. Scroll down a little  bit you will see **Web Server Settings.**. Check the URL and set it to new port. For example if it is: http://localhost:3798 change it to http://localhost:3979 or vice-versa. Changing the port number might solve your issue. Press **Ctrl + S** to save it.
4. Build the solution and re-run the project without Debugging (Ctrl +F5).
5. Open your Bot Framework Emulator and enter the URL that you mentioned in step 3 above.

**Note:** This doesn't mean it will 100% work, but this is one of the solution that I come across. I had the same problem and I solved it same way.

Hope this helps.