# Cannot connect C# Basic bot to Bot Framework Emulator

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

This is my current screen when I have tried to load my bot into the bot Framework Emulator:
[image]

And this is what I have entered within the setting for my bot:
[image]

I have not modified the code I have only entered the MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppPassword, and the AzureWebStorage.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you're running it locally I don't think you need the ID and password in the emulator. Probably won't make any difference but worth a try, right? :)

Comment: Tried adding in the app ID and password but no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot link bot to bot framework emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186403/cannot-link-bot-to-bot-framework-emulator)

Comment: Hi @L.Full, you could create [an issue in github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues) to describe and report it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you started the bot correctly, the two things that jump out at me is making sure the port number is correct and (my main guess) adding http:// to the beginning of the address registered in the emulator.

Comment: I've added the http:// to the address and still no joy. Could you expand on the "Assuming you started the bot correctly" maybe there is something I missed when starting it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- As [@geektrainer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7864769/geektrainer) mentioned, make sure that the port number is correct (3984 is not one of the default ports).
- Adding http:// to the address is required.
- If you are entering the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword within your code, they also need to be entered into the emulator (under Application ID and Application Password).

Comment: When I run my bot fro Visual studio it displays in the web browsers search bar localhost:3984/ . I have tried putting the application ID and Application password in and adding http:// into the address but no luck

Comment: When you say 'putting in the application ID', do you mean in the emulator, or in the code? If you're running a simple echo bot locally, you don't need to put it in either place.

Comment: As @JJ_Wailes pointed out, could you try removing the Microsoft App ID & password from both your code and the emulator? If that doesn't work, feel free to send me a link to your repo and I will take a look.

Comment: @Corina what is your user name so I can grant access?

Comment: @Corina Also which repo do you want access to? as I noticed that you are mentioned in my other issue which is similar to this

Comment: If they're separate repos you can go ahead and add me to both. I see you already added me to the QNA maker one. Let's figure this out. :)